# Insert "Select" in dropdown with LInq

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, drop-down-menu

I have loaded the drop down box from LINQ,

> CustomerDataContext customer = new
>   CustomerDataContext();
>
> ```
>     ddlCust.DataSource = from cust in customerDC.Customers
>                              orderby cust.CustId ascending  
>                              select new {cust.CustId,
> ```
>
> cust.CustName} ;
>
> ```
>     ddlCust.DataTextField = "CustName";
>     ddlCust.DataValueField = "CustId";
>     ddlCust.DataBind();
> ```

it is working fine but I want item of drop down list as :

Text: Select
Value: 0

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
....
....
ddlCust.DataBind();  
ddlCust.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Value:", "0"));
```

Comment: Thanks for this fast response :-)